# Different data types for time

Tags: ado.net

What are the different data types for time attributes in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.DateTime` is only one type for date and time in .NET

Update:

Very good articles about SQL Server date and time types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx

Comment: i m not talk about name space please tell me regarding database data type for datatime which is used in asp.net.

Comment: @picnic4u: You tagged your question `asp.net` - I thought you're talking about ASP.NET. If you mean ADO.NET and some database engine - please edit your question to be more specific. Indicate what type of DB do you use - SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.

Comment: u are right i have edited my question so pls suggest me datatype